# Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer

Tags: npm, electron, pcap

I am creating an application with ElectronJS, Node, and Node pcap. I made the interface and everything is fine. But, when I import my backend code, I get an error:

```
Unresolved error: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '/home/bibi/Music/WireElectron/node_modules/pcap/build/Release/pcap_binding.node'.
```

The problem I have is that it is due to a simple line `const pcap = require('pcap')`. Seeing this error I looked it up and found that I needed to add a line, which I did.

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false
    createWindow()
```

Here is my index.js :

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1020,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        },
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')
}


app.whenReady().then(() => {
    app.allowRendererProcessReuse = false
    createWindow()

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow()
        }
    })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

I have tried several techniques found on forums but nothing works, could someone help me ?

Thanks for help

Comment: What version of Electron are you using? `app.allowRendererProcessReuse` was [removed](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-appallowrendererprocessreuse) in Electron version 14.0 Additionally, please add the line where you `require(‘pcap’)`. Lastly, have you [installed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap#installation) `pcap` correctly, primarily the compile phase.

Comment: Curenlty im using electron 23.0.0. I'm requiring pcap in my app.js file, which control all the backend script of my page, opposite to index.js which have the basics functions of Electron. 
When i saw your comment i followed your link and i installed it like it was explained on the web page, but nothing changed.